# Tibco BusinessWorks 6.x versions

Tags: version, backwards-compatibility, tibco, incompatibility, tibco-business-works

Do you guys know if there is some sort of incompatibilities among the  BusinessWorks 6.x versions? I'm going to use the version 6.4.2 to import an existing project created with a previous 6.x version, is that ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not too many incompatibilities problems. Just some XSD schema validation (Every import in an xsd schema must have the schemalocation in addition to namespace), or warning (unoptimized xpath mapping  ..).

BW 6.4 is more stricter compared to earlier versions